# Perl Script (for calling Mac::AppleScript Perl module)

Tags: perl, applescript

I'm setting up some automation using shell and applescript scripting. Several of my modules require passing several params into the AppleScript. Although there are a few ways of doing so, a bit of research lead me to the "Mac::AppleScript Perl module" and it looks really promising. However it requires a short .pl script in /usr/local/bin. The only example of it I found has two syntax errors and I have absolutely no experience at all in Perl.

I've tried guessing at what might be throwing the errors based on what I would use in the languages I've worked with but even though I can recognize the variables not expanding in a few spots, my attempts at correcting it results in further errors and I've been hacking at it for hours. Can someone please take a look and tell me what might be the syntax issues I can fix?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use Mac::AppleScript qw/ RunAppleScript /;

if( $#ARGV = 0) ? '"'.join('","',@ARGV).'"' : "";
my $rtn = RunAppleScript( "return run script alias ((POSIX file ""
    .$script.'") as text) with parameters {'.$args.'}' ),"n"
        or die "AppleScript Error: $!";

$rtn =~ s/(^"|"$)//g;
print $rtn,"n";
```

Answer (score 1):

Problems:

- You have an unescaped `"` in your double-quoted string literal.
- You use variables you never declared or initialized.
- You have a stray `,"n"` in your code.
- Your code suffers from [code injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_injection) bugs.
- The error message is found in `$@`, not `$!`.

Fixed:

```
sub text_to_as_lit { '"'.( $_[0] =~ s/([\\"])/\\$1/rg ).'"' }  #'

my ($script, @args) = @ARGV;

my $rtn = RunAppleScript(sprintf(
   "return run script alias ((POSIX file %s) as text) with parameters {%s}",
   text_to_as_lit($script),
   ( join ',', map text_to_as_lit($_), @args ),
))
    or die("AppleScript Error: $@");
```

Untested.